# splitting up a MySQL dump using awk

Tags: awk

I have a large-ish (250G) MySQL dump file from which I only want / need one database. I was hoping to use **awk** to split the file up so I did some searching and [found](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/awk-10-examples-to-split-file-into.html) this expression:

```
awk '/START/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' file2
```

Seems like a good start (and works well using their sample file) but running it as:

```
awk '/CREATE DATABASE/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' file2
```

gives me errors like this:

```
awk: (FILENAME=dump_all.sql FNR=1) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value
```

Other pages (from SE) report that this is due to hitting a blank line.

I'd love to use this technique to get the part that I want out of this file but my knowledge of **awk** syntax is (clearly) quite limited. Is there some way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your actual issue. Since you haven't shown us the actual input file, I have no idea if what you are attempting will even work. In any case, to fix the error you're getting, use this:

```
awk '/CREATE DATABASE/{x="F"++i;}(x){print > x;}' file2
```

That modifies the script to only attempt to print to file `x` if the variable `x` is set. The error you were getting was because it was attempting to print all lines, some of which apparently are before the `CREATE DATABASE` string at which point `x` was unset. The script above is equivalent to writing:

```
awk '{
      if(/CREATE DATABASE/){i=i+1; x="F"i;}
      if(x!=NULL){print > x }
     }' file2
```